# Alfresco: retrieve number of contents created per user

Tags: alfresco

I'm workink on an Alfresco project and our customer ask me to create a page where the administrator can see how many documents has been uploaded per user.
What's the best way to achieve that?
I start looking at lucene query, but I discovers that it only returns max 1000 results... so if a user uploaded more documents, the information will be useless.
Any idea?
I can use a custom jsp inside Alfresco, a webscript, or something external that uses REST service... I haven't any restriction... I just need to do such reporting page.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options then one. 
First, you can increase the limit from number of lucene results by modifiying repository.properties:

```
index.tracking.maxRecordSetSize=1000
```

Second option, what I personally use, is to have a webscript which goes through all sites and all folders in the document libraries recursively and then generates a more verbose output, something like:

```
Site |   Number of docs uploaded

Site1 | total: 500
      users: 
      x: 200 documents
      y: 300 documents
Site2 | ....
```

It all depends on whether you want to also check only for docs uploaded this month, or something like that.

Comment: So basically you have to count the documents manually... there's no kind of query you can perform to get that numbers!?!?
I mean, something like "Select count(*) from documents where userid=x"